# Dotfuscator failing on Xamarin UWP project

Tags: xamarin, uwp, dotfuscator

I have a Xamarin Forms app that I have integrated Dotfuscator CE successfully with both Android and iOS.  Now I am trying integrate with UWP but get a build error when Dotfuscator runs.  I turned on the more verbose output and see this:

`[Build Output] Couldn't load external type because its assembly can't be found: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page,Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

I followed the same directions I used for Android and iOS and updated both Dotfuscator CE (5.40.0.8950) and Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.9.5).  Any ideas?  Is protecting UWP not possible with Dotfuscator CE?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to tell Dotfuscator where to find the `UniversalApiContract` if the location changed since earlier SDK versions. I found mine here, your path may differ depending on which version you have:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\7.0.0.0
```

To tell Dotfuscator Community to look in this additional directory:

1. Launch the Dotfuscator Config Editor (GUI) from Visual Studio by selecting *Tools > PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator Community*.
2. Open the `DotfuscatorConfig.xml` file for your UWP project.
3. Under [*Settings > Assembly Load Paths*](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_settings.html#pctoc-assembly-load-paths-tab), click the green plus icon to add a path, paste the path to the directory, and click OK.
4. Save the config file.

Afterward, try building the project from Visual Studio again.

(*Note: I work for the Dotfuscator team and am answering as part of my job.*)

Comment: Adding this led to the following error: ```error : ILT0040: Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContract' was not found. Check that your build system references Windows.winmd, references .NET for Windows Store Apps, and is configured to use .NET Native.``` I unchecked "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" and now it is building.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it crashed on launch with the error: ```Unable to activate Windows Store app...Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040904``` I don't get this crash when turning off Dotfuscator on the release build.

Comment: @cncb You may need to exclude certain parts of your app from Dotfuscator's renaming obfuscation. The specific exclusions will differ depending on the app. Some resources: [how to configure renaming exclusions via the Config Editor in Dotfuscator Community](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_renaming.html#pctoc-exclusions-tab), and [some examples of exploring/discovering renaming exclusions](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_exclusions.html) (written for Dotfuscator Professional, but the concepts are the same for Community).

Comment: I have added all the necessary exclusions for my Xamarin Forms dll but I have no idea what would be required for the UWP exe part of it (it crashes on launch during "activation").  It seems there should be an obvious class or method to exclude from renaming for UWP.  I have tried to exclude the App and Program types from renaming with no success but I don't know what would be involved in "activation".

Comment: @cncb Maybe try temporarily disabling renaming entirely to see if that's the problem? Keep in mind if you exclude a type, only the name of the type is excluded from renaming, names of its members will need to be excluded separately.

Comment: Disabling renaming entirely allows it to launch.  Also, excluding just my Xamarin Forms assembly (.NET Standard) works. I am guessing it may be due to disabling "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" but I don't know how to fix the missing type build error associated with that.

Comment: After more research, it seems like Dotfuscator is unnecessary when compiling UWP with .NET Native enabled since this results in native code dlls that cannot be disassembled?  Is this correct?

Comment: While native compilation can make it difficult to reverse engineer an app, Dotfuscator can still make it even harder.